# Dynamically Slide a div based on the input entered in the text filed which is matched in the div content

Tags: jquery

I have one Text Field which is used to type the text, By using that text I need to filter the data from the div. The div contains some 100 list of values(`<li>..</li>`).

If the text is matched in the div, then iam able to change the background of that li element.

But the problem is, If the matched text is the last element in the div, then i need to slide down the div manually, But my requirement is to slide the div automatically to the matched element position.
For Example,

```
var array = [
    "First Element","Second Element","Third Element","Fourth Element",
    "Fifth Element","Sixth Element","Seventh Element",
    "Eighth Element","Ninth Element","Tenth Element",
    "Eleventh Element","Twelth Element","Thirteen Element",
    "Fourteen Element","Fifteen Element","Sixteen Element",
    "Seventeen Element","Eighteen Element","Ninteen Element",
    "Twenty Element","Twenty one Element",
    "Twenty two Element","Twenty three Element","Twenty Fouth Element",
    "Twenty Fifth Element","Twenty Sixth Element","Twenty Seventh Element",
    "Twenty Eighth Element","Twenty Ninth Element"
];

$("#filter").keyup(function()
{
    var typedText = $(this).val();
    $("#list").find("li").css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
    $.each(array, function(id,obj)
    {           
        if(obj.toLowerCase().indexOf(typedText.toLowerCase()) != -1)
        {
            $("#list").find("li:contains(" + typedText + ")").css({'background-color': '#ccc'});
        } 
    })      
})
```

I tried a lot but unable to reach the solution.Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: _"I tried a lot"_ Please show your efforts in your question.

Comment: For Every keyup in the textfield, I need to filter from the div, if any part of an element is matched from the div with the typed text, then div automatically slide to point to the first occurrance of an element.

Comment: Matched exactly orr just a in parte...i have posted an example.

Comment: Hey, have you solved?

Comment: if a part is matched also, slide the div to the matched element

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you need. But maybe it's something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/6ufmdgyw/  or http://jsfiddle.net/6ufmdgyw/1/

Use the :eq selector to select the right matched element.

```
$("#filter").keyup(function()
{
    var typedText = $(this).val();
    $("#list").find("li").css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
    $.each(array, function(id,obj)
    {           
        if(obj.toLowerCase().indexOf(typedText.toLowerCase()) != -1)
        {
            $("#list").find("li:eq("+id+")").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#list").find("li:eq("+id+")").slideUp();
        }
    })      
})
```

the key is `.find("li:eq("+id+")")`

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code on JS Fiddle given by @Kharchi . Hope this match to your requirement.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishoreworks/acd62t15/1/embedded/result/)

```
 var array = [
    "First Element","Second Element","Third Element","Fourth Element",
    "Fifth Element","Sixth Element","Seventh Element",
    "Eighth Element","Ninth Element","Tenth Element",
    "Eleventh Element","Twelth Element","Thirteen Element",
    "Fourteen Element","Fifteen Element","Sixteen Element",
    "Seventeen Element","Eighteen Element","Ninteen Element",
    "Twenty Element","Twenty one Element",
    "Twenty two Element","Twenty three Element","Twenty Fouth Element",
    "Twenty Fifth Element","Twenty Sixth Element","Twenty Seventh Element",
    "Twenty Eighth Element","Twenty Ninth Element"
];

$.each(array, function(c,e) {
    $('#list').append('<li>'+e+'</li>');
});


$("#filter").keyup(function()
{
    offsetStart = true;
    var typedText = $(this).val();
    $("#list").find("li").css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
    $.each(array, function(id,obj)
    {           
        if(obj.toLowerCase().indexOf(typedText.toLowerCase()) != -1)
        {
            $("#list").find("li:eq("+id+")").css({'background-color': '#ccc'})
            if(offsetStart){
                tempOffset = $("#list").find("li:eq("+id+")").offset().top;
                $(window).scrollTop( tempOffset );
                offsetStart = false;
            }
        } 
    })      
})
```